# When I open a new tab in chrome, I get a new character inserted automatically

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

When I open a new tab in chrome, I get a new character inserted automatically - the letter `א`.

This only happens when the keyboard layout is in Hebrew and opening a new tab using the `ctrl+T` keyboard showrtcut. See scrrencap below. (The auto-suggest isn't important)

It seems that this is obvious as the letter `א` is on the same key as `T`.

Any idea how to prevent the additional `א` from being added?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem in Google Chrome (Ubuntu) when I open the new Tab (using Ctrl+T) in Cyrillic keyboard layout (Russian or Ukrainian). But if I open the new Tab in English keyboard layout It's all Okay...